# why is my program ignoring parts of my code (in c)

Tags: c

I've written this piece of code to see if I could convert simple numbers from decimal to, for example, binary numbers per base (e.g. binary base = 2) I know it wouldn't really be the correct number for hex, or anything above base = 9 for that matter, (that's why I added a space in `printf (temp[I])` so I could see the separate base^index-1 ) but here's my problem: after compiling and running it, I can enter decimal and base, then it prints those 2 and then... nothing. It's ignoring `convert();` and `for(){printf}` completely for some reason. PS: the reason I `calloc` exactly decimal times `sizeof int` is because maybe some one types base = 1 yk just in case. Also wouldn't really matter, as I count the length of the array anyway per int counter, right?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void convert(int decimal, int base, int counter, int temp[])
{
    int remainder;
    int quotient;
    int i = 0;
    while (decimal > 0)
    {
        remainder = decimal % base; // remainder is stored
        quotient = (decimal - remainder) / base; //quotient is stored
        decimal = quotient; // decimal is assigned quotient for next operation
        counter++; //counter is incremented so we can printf correct lentgh of array
        temp[i] = remainder; // sets our array at i = remainder
        i = i + 1; //to increment i for every decimal > 0
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int decimal;
    int base;

    //enterNumbers(decimal, base); // doesnt work yet

    printf("enter decimal:");
    scanf("%d", &decimal);
    printf("enter base:");
    scanf("%d", &base);
    // gets input decimal and base
    int *temp = calloc(decimal, sizeof(int));
    // alloc memory for array, worst case base = 1
    printf("decimal:%d, base:%d", decimal, base);
    // for test

    convert(decimal, base, counter, temp);
    // converts decimal into base number and sorts into array

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", temp[i]);
    }
    //should printf the array, which is the base number

    return 0;
}
```

well as stated above

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code?

Comment: In C, function arguments are passed by value. Which means that the `counter` variable in the function is not the same as the `counter` variable in `main`. Try adding a printf to `main` that shows the value of `counter` after calling the function.

Comment: By the way, talking about a base of 1 is meaningless – you only have one single digit available to represent numbers, which is 0 – so all you can represent is the number 0 as well. If you really care about then you should catch this as a special case print an appropriate error message (`if(base <= 1) { ... } else { /* what you have now */ }`).

Comment: Requesting as many digits as the number's value is just a waste of memory – you'd reserve 8G of memory (32-bit int provided) for numbers near `INT_MAX` though you'd need at most 32 digits even for base 2... What you actual need is the logarithm of the number to the base, which you could calculate as `ceil(log(decimal)/log(base))` – and I'd yet add one just for the case some rounding might lead to a value too little by one.

Comment: A bit of cosmetics: Have you ever noticed that `i` and `counter` will always hold the same value? So you could drop `i` entirely and access `temp` via `counter`, though you'd need to increment *after* assigning `remainder` to. I personally would rather go with the pointer arithmetics: `*temp++ = remainder;`, skipping both `i` and `counter` entirely. You might then return `temp` and within main you could calculate the number of digits contained by subtracting the original pointer from: (`int* end = convert(...); int count = end - temp;`.

Comment: Alternatively you calculate the count within convert, then you need to remember the original value of `temp`: `int* tmp = temp; /* increment tmp with every digit */ return tmp - temp;` with a return type of `size_t` for `convert` function.

Comment: @Abra I do not know how to debug code. for reference, I have no coding experience but the first month of university rn (comp sci and elec eng)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that in C *all* function parameters are passed *by value*, which means that the *value is copied* into the parameter (which actually is just some special kind of local variable).

The result of is that the function modifies its own copy of while the original variable within `main` remains unchanged, thus your `for` loop printing the array runs from 0 up to (not including) 0, i.e. is not entered at all.

If you want to be able to modify a variable you pass to function you only can do so by passing the *address* of the variable to the function, which in C is done via a pointer:

```
void convert(int decimal, int base, int* counter, int temp[])
//                                     ^ (!)
{
    // code as is, but use *counter instead of counter now
}
```

Note that actually the same applies for the `temp` array, with *function parameters* (not everywhere else!) `int temp[]` is exactly equivalent to `int* temp`, so you again are just passing a pointer to the array.

Note, too, that `i` and `*counter` will after every loop run hold the same value, after loop completion both will hold the total number of digits contained. So you don't need to increment the counter with every loop run, but instead can assign `i` to it *after* the loop completed.

You'd now need to pass the address of the counter integer to the function:

```
convert(decimal, base, &counter, temp);
//                     ^ (!)
```

There's yet a better alternative, though: Functions can have return values, and instead of writing to a variable passed to which doesn't actually transport any information into the function you can use the return value to transport this information back.

As mentioned `i` holds the value of interest already. So just return it:

```
size_t convert(int decimal, int base, temp)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    // rest as you have, dropping any references to counter
    return i;
}
```

Note that I changed the counter type to `size_t` (you need to `#include<stddef.h>` for) – it is the semantically correct type for indicating memory sizes and so on. It's an unsigned type large enough to hold the size of any allocatable type on your system. If you don't like you can return an `unsigned int` as well (even `int`, but I'd prefer an unsigned value to indicate that negative values are meaningless anyway).

Finally: You missed a special case! If `decimal` is zero already you won't print out anything. You should catch this case separately and fill a single null value into the array returning 1 immediately.

Apart from the issues with `convert` function you have a memory leak for not freeing `temp` again after having used it (lacks `free(temp)`) and you might want to check the return values of `calloc` and `scanf` to catch failed memory allocation and invalid user input. Be aware, though, that `scanf` will scan for a string containing some digits followed by some non-digits (like `1210dal`) only scan the numerical parts and ignore the non-digits (leading to failure of next digits to read) so checking the return value only is not safe in the general case (you might read an entire string or a complete line with `fgets` instead and parse this one, checking if all characters of have been consumed).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues that I addressed:

1. In `main()` you initialize the variable to `counter = 0` and do not change it after that.  This means the `for()` where you print the result doesn't run.  Arguments are passed by value in c, this means the value is copied, if you want to have an effect in the caller you can either return a value, or you can pass in a pointer to the variable (you can also use a global variable but we don't speak about that in polite company).
2. If `decimal == 0` you are allocating a zero sized array which is implementation defined, and would likely result in a out of bounds write.
3. Error checking of `scanf()` and `calloc()`.
4. `free()` the `temp` buffer.

Here's passing in a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert(int decimal, int base, int *counter, int temp[])
{
    int remainder;
    int quotient;
    int i = 0;
    while (decimal > 0)
    {
        remainder = decimal % base; // remainder is stored
        quotient = (decimal - remainder) / base; //quotient is stored
        decimal = quotient; // decimal is assigned quotient for next operation
        (*counter)++; //counter is incremented so we can printf correct lentgh of array
        temp[i] = remainder; // sets our array at i = remainder
        i = i + 1; //to increment i for every decimal > 0
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int decimal;
    int base;

    //enterNumbers(decimal, base); // doesnt work yet

    printf("enter decimal:");
    if(scanf("%d", &decimal) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("enter base:");
    if(scanf("%d", &base) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // gets input decimal and base
    int *temp = calloc(decimal, sizeof(int));
    if(!temp) {
        printf("calloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // alloc memory for array, worst case base = 1
    printf("decimal:%d, base:%d", decimal, base);
    // for test

    convert(decimal + 1, base, &counter, temp);
    // converts decimal into base number and sorts into array

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", temp[i]);
    }
    //should printf the array, which is the base number
    free(temp);
}
```

and example run (observe that the result is reversed of the usual notation):

```
enter decimal:10
enter base:2
decimal:10, base:2 0, 1, 0, 1,
```

Here's a more heavily revised version that returns the count, uses a smaller data type than 'int' for each digit, and statically allocates an array sufficiently large to hold the largest decimal with the smallest base (on my system that is 64 bytes).  With original code `10 * sizeof(int) = 80`.  It also tweaks the prompts for readability and reverses the output per convention of most significant value first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <values.h>

void print(size_t n, unsigned char a[n], const char *field_separator, const char *record_separator) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i + 1 < n ? field_separator : record_separator);
    }
}

size_t reverse(size_t n, unsigned char a[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        unsigned char tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[(n-1)-i];
        a[(n-1)-i] = tmp;
    }
    return n;
}

int convert(unsigned decimal, unsigned base, unsigned char temp[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; decimal > 0; i++) {
        temp[i] = decimal % base;
        decimal = (decimal - temp[i]) / base;
    }
    return reverse(i, temp);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("enter decimal: ");
    unsigned decimal;
    if(scanf("%u", &decimal) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("enter base: ");
    unsigned base;
    if(scanf("%u", &base) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(base < 2 || base > 10) {
        printf("base must be between 2 and 10\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char temp[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
    int counter = convert(decimal, base, temp);
    print(counter, temp, ", ", "\n");
}
```

and example run:

```
enter decimal: 10
enter base: 2
1, 0, 1, 0
```

Comment: Actually I'd rather recommend to `return` the number of digits, which would be the final value of `i`, and drop `counter` entirely. *If* retaining `counter` as output parameter I wouldn't increment with every loop run, but simply assign the final value of `i` to. Checking the result of `calloc` is just as essential as checking the one of `scanf`, you should add this hint, too.

Comment: @Aconcagua I will add the hint re calloc, although I disagree with being as essential.  It's way easier to enter a non-digits than exhausting memory.   I usually try to make minimal changes to ease understanding (in this case pass by value vs pointer).  For instance, I would use `for()` in convert as it fits naturally.

Comment: Well, essential from programme safety point of view – maybe me having been to long into this sector ;) Indeed, bad user input occurs much more easily than memory allocation failing. On value vs pointer: You might yet add an introductory paragraph explaining the by-value aspect of parameters – clarifying why changing `counter` to a pointer is necessary at all...